# Using multiple AVAudioSequencer with one or more AVAudioUnitSampler

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine

Context:
I am trying to play multiple MIDI sequences in an iOS app using `AVFoundation`. The tracks are loaded in MIDI files and I have successfully managed to play them one by one if I load them in a `AVAudioSequencer`. I also have an `AVAudioUnitSampler` object which is connected in an `AVAudioEngine` and it successfully plays the selected instrument from the loaded sound bank in the sampler.

The setup works correctly if I create a new `AVAudioSequencer` each time I play a sound. However, if I would like to reuse a sequencer after it's finished, it sounds like it's not using the sampler's instrument.

I suspect when I create the `AVAudioSequencer` objects they are automatically connected to the `AVAudioEngine` but only the last object will get the connected to the sampler.

I've tried to manually connect the `destinationAudioUnit` of the tracks in the sequencer to the sampler, but then it doesn't play a sound at all. I also tried to make multiple samplers and connect them all to the engine, but that didn't work either.

**My main question is: What is the proper way of using multiple `AVAudioSequencer` objects with one `AVAudioUnitSampler`? Or do I need to create a sampler for each sequencer and connect them somehow?**

Here's a very basic playground example of two sequencers. When I run it, sequencer B successfully plays the sound through the sampler, but A is not using the instrument.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let buttonA = UIButton(type: .system), buttonB = UIButton(type: .system)
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    lazy var sequencerA = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: engine)
    lazy var sequencerB = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: engine)
    let sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

    // UI setup
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        buttonA.setTitle("Sequencer A", for: .normal)
        buttonB.setTitle("Sequencer B", for: .normal)
        buttonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playSequencerA), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playSequencerB), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(buttonA)
        view.addSubview(buttonB)
        buttonA.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        buttonB.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100)
        self.view = view
    }

    // Sound engine setup
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        engine.attach(sampler)
        engine.connect(sampler, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        let soundBankPath = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("gs_instruments.dls")
        let midiA = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sfx_a.mid")
        let midiB = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sfx_b.mid")
        try! sampler.loadSoundBankInstrument(at: soundBankPath, program: 11, bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB), bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB))
        try! sequencerA.load(from: midiA, options: [])
        try! sequencerB.load(from: midiB, options: [])
        try! engine.start()
    }

    @objc public func playSequencerA() { play(sequencerA) }

    @objc public func playSequencerB() { play(sequencerB) }

    func play(_ sequencer: AVAudioSequencer) {
        if sequencer.isPlaying { sequencer.stop() }
        sequencer.currentPositionInBeats = 0
        try! sequencer.start()
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Edit:
After some additional experiments I suspect that the `AVAudioEngine` cannot have more than one `AVAudioSequencer` instance (or I'm still doing something wrong). As a workaround, I have created a separate `AVAudioEngine` object for each MIDI file that I need to play and they all have their own sampler and sequencer inputs, which plays the sounds just fine. I'm pretty sure this solution is not optimal, so I would be glad for any tips about a better setup.